# SharePoint Sites created by MS Teams, & Planner

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-admin-center, microsoft-planner

In SPO Admin Center i see many sites which are created by the users. I understand MS Planner, MS Teams runs off the groups service and a SharePoint site is created.

For auditing purpose i would like to get a list of sites that was created by these apps(planner, Teams)

**Is there a way to find out who created the site and how was the site created**

Any suggestions will be helpful- thanks for your time and help

Comment: I have same need.
From Sharepoint admin console, i can read in the properties of a site things as Other info
Created ‎12/21/23‎ at ‎7:15 PM‎ by ‎
2024 Bulk Maintenance Owners ‎from ‎Planner‎ I think the good approach is to use any command as get-sposite or get-pnpweb/get-pnpsite , and understand the field where the value "planner" is written. Any suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want to find these... PowerShell, admin pages, etc.

I'll look around to see if there is a single simple solution. In the mean time are some options:

One is to use the Office Audit Logs: https://protection.office.com/unifiedauditlog and do searches for "Created Site", "Created Team" etc. The data may not go back as far as you need.

Another is to use the SPO PowerShell cmdlets. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-the-SharePoint-Online-Management-Shell-C16941C3-19B4-4710-8056-34C034493429

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://yourDomain-admin.sharepoint.com
Get-SPOSite | select url, template, owner
```

Sites listed without (Site Collection) owners are most likely Office 365 Group sites, which include Team created sites. The template will give you a hint as to the purpose of the site. (Team sites use the "Group#0" template.) The "owner" is the Site Collection Admin, which be default is the person who created the site collection, but can be changed after the site is created.

To get just the team sites:

```
Get-SPOSite -Template GROUP#0  | select url, template, owner
```

You can also inspect the list of Active Directory Groups. Those that have (group) "Owners" and/or (group) "Members" are either Modern Sites created by users or Modern Sites created to back up Teams, Planner, etc.

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
Get-Group | select displayname, grouptype, managedby, owners, members
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to helping me out, i looked at the suggestions that you provided, i almost got 90% of my report using the Powershell commands you provided. I still need to figure out how to find which Modern team site was created using which app (planner, teams) 
Since all modern team site are using Group#0 template. Any thoughts or suggestions on that ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a PowerShell cmdlet for everything! Here's how to get Teams and the related site. (Haven't found how to get the Planners yet...)

```
install-module MicrosoftTeams
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

# connect to AD (same as in previous answer)
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking

Get-Team | foreach { Get-UnifiedGroup -Identity $_.GroupId } | select DisplayName, SharePointSiteUrl
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful & i appreciate your time.